# SQL for grouping data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table in Oracle db from which I migrate data to my schema. I must migrate it in many threads but I must have data with specific event_owner in on thread..

```
desc EVENTS
Name             Null     Type         
---------------- -------- ------------ 
EVENT_OWNER                 NUMBER       
EVENT_SOURCE NOT NULL NUMBER       
EVENT_CATEGORY                 VARCHAR2(14) 


EVENT_OWNER EVENT_SOURCE EVENT_CATEGORY
1           A            B   
5           A            C
3           A            B
1           X            E
4           A            B
5           A            C
7           A            C
8           A            C
```

Is it possible (and how to do that) to make a query that will return for example three owners and all of their events, such as:

```
1           A            B   
1           X            E

4           A            B

5           A            C
5           A            C
```

(the migration process will mark owners during migration, so i will be able to append to that query

> "and EVENT_OWNER not in (select owners during migration)"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one works:

```
with owners as (
  select distinct EVENT_OWNER
  from EVENTS
  where rownum<=3
  -- "and EVENT_OWNER not in (select owners during migration)"
  )
select e.*
from EVENTS e
  join owners o
    on e.EVENT_OWNER=o.EVENT_OWNER
order by e.EVENT_OWNER
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is like this. but I wonder if such simple thing could be what you want...

```
select * from EVENTS
where EVENT_OWNER in (/* specify owners here, or select owners from somewhere */)
order by EVENT_OWNER
```

Comment: not really, the hardest is this /* specify owners here, or select owners from somewhere */ , i canoperate only on EVENTS table

Comment: then, you can specify EVENT_OWNER numbers directly. it'll be something like "EVENT_OWNER in (1, 4, 5)"

Comment: Dude (@michealAtmi), you explain yourserlf really bad. It's going to be impossible to find someone able to help you with the information that you give.

Comment: You have an example in the original post